# Cell boundaries disappear when colouring

Tags: excel, vba

I have a use case where I have to toggle between the colors in a cell using VBA. But when I try to change a cell color from any color to white its boundaries disappear. Can anyone tell me what to write so that the color of cell changes to white without losing its boundaries.

Here is my code

```vb
If Range("C1").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
    Range("C1").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
End If
```

[image]

Comment: This is the correct result that you get when you apply an interior color to a cell. The cells do not have visible borders by default. Excel displays them to you as a courtesy when the cell interior is not set. If you want actual borders, set them as actual borders.

Comment: How to set them as actual Borders in Excel.Cannot we set the boundaries of the cell to default after changing its color to white Using VBA

Comment: Don't set the colour to white, set it to nothing: `Range("A1").Interior.ColorIndex = 0` or `Range("A1").Interior.Color = xlNone`

Comment: The cell borders on your picture are set to default. The default is no borders, so they correctly don't display. Apparently you believe that the default interior color is white to begin with; it is not, the [default color index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.interior.colorindex#remarks) is `xlColorIndexNone`.

Comment: Thanks @jamheadart For the Info.It works